# How to interpret なりました at a baseball game radio broadcast?

Tags: pragmatics, semantics, interpretation

On my local radio station baseball games translations take the most of the broadcast slots. Commentators speak very fast and the only thing I can differentiate is なりました. なりました is repeated literally every two seconds. What could possibly "become" or "change state" so often? What is possibly said in front of なりました?

Comment: This is a very good question, I was wondering myself too.

Comment: It could be when they're stating the strike/ball count, like "2ストライク、3ボールに「なりました」"? The count would usually be repeated over and over again. It's also something that is constantly changing.

Comment: It's going to be hard to say with so little information, and partial at that. Perhaps you could upload a sample?

Comment: @Nutkin are we talking about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kHRkCTg4JY ? The commentator repeats なりました in the beginning. Also it could be characteristic of 楠淳生 to say it often but I haven't watched (or listened) any 野球 before so I'm not sure. To me the use sounds similar to キター

Comment: @siikamiika You mean at 0:02? He says 「投{な}げました打{う}ちました！」 (The pitch and a hit!) there. It's very fast and does kind of sound like 「なりました」. If this is what user1602 was talking about, then it means "to throw". However, I'd like a sample to be certain.

Comment: @Jimmy Yeah, that one. How about what he says after that? 「高く...ました」

Comment: @siikamiika Right after that? Sounds like 「高{たか}～く舞{まい}い上{あ}がった！」, "It's flying high into the air!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...に、なりました。　...に、なりました。　...に、なりました。　...に、なりました。

This is a fresh discovery that I have not ever thought it to be questionable as a Japanese at all.

You could not hear the same phrase on TV broadcast, right?

「になりました」 is used to convey every happening event to the listeners who are not watching it.

The reporter could say "ただいま午後｛ごご｝３時｛じ｝２４分｛ぷん｝１０秒｛びょう｝**になりました**。１１秒｛びょう｝**になりました**。１２秒｛びょう｝**になりました**。...." on every second for ever.